# Broken ubuntu distibution

Tags: boot, system-installation, desktop-environments

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 as my main distro. Recently I installed several additional desktop environments, including:
*Cairo*, *Cinnamon*, *Pantheon*, *Deepin*, and most recently *Xubuntu*.

I always had trouble booting into *Pantheon* and *Deepin* so I wanted to uninstall them. So, for Deepin I went to the file in my sources file and deleted to lines I had added, and subsquently went into Synaptic and deleted everything with "Deepin" in its name. Then for *Pantheon* I did (i think):

```
sudo apt-get purge pantheon
```

Upon rebooting into Ubuntu itself, I saw a blank blue home page, but no unity interface at all, I could do nothing but press and hold the power button and restart.

How can I make Ubuntu boot again?

Comment: A screenshot would help. Try re-installing ubuntu-desktop: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @Seth Since `ubuntu-desktop` is a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages), will that command actually cause any software to be reinstalled?

Comment: @michael-dykes What repositories were added/removed?  Were these PPAs?  Were these repositories manually added to `sources.list`?  What repositories remain on your system?

Comment: You probably only messed up your login manager. For starters, you can switch to a terminal via CTRL-ALT-F1. You should then see if you can manually start xfce via `startxfce4`

Comment: @EliahKagan Good question, I hadn't thought of that. Many people seem to use it, so I assume so. I have no thorough way of testing it at the moment.

Comment: Michael, I recently answered this same question. Check the following link for a solution. http://askubuntu.com/questions/525829/greeter-for-lightdm-not-accepting-changes/526679?noredirect=1#comment717611_526679

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you attempt to reconfigure/reinstall some packages. try running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop lightdm pantheon deepin` then `sudo dpkg reconfigure ubuntu-desktop lightdm`. If that doesn't work you may need to fix a few corrupt packages or something. Try using `sudo apt-get -f install` along with the usual autoclean, clean, update, upgrade, and autoremove commands.

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop lightdm pantheon deepin' but only got:  Unable to locate package pantheon Unable to locate package deepin. Then upon trying:`sudo apt-get -f install' I get: The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  vlc-plugin-pulse
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: first do the autoremove it's saying to do then try going the command I gave without putting in pantheon or deepin

Comment: I did the autoremove, then the command you gave without the pantheon or deepin then rebooted and tried to boot back into Ubuntu. Upon doing so, all I got was a plain blue screen (with the mouse from Xubuntu) and no Unity interface or anything that I could do anything with. At that point all I knew to do was to hold down power button and ``hard reboot''.

Comment: did you reconfigure lightdm? try installing gdm and see if that works

Comment: Sorry, (am really new to this)... upon entering `sudo apt-get install gdm'   I get: gdm is already the newest version.
gdm set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Thanks.

Comment: sudo dpkg --reconfigure gdm

Comment: and set it as default

Comment: When I try that I get: dpkg: error: unknown option --reconfigure

Comment: one moment I need to find the actual command

Comment: try just reconfigure without the hyphens

Comment: Now I get: dpkg: error: need an action option   Thanks.

Comment: oh...it's dpkg-reconfigure gdm

Comment: And then do I just try rebooting into Ubuntu?

Comment: does it prompt you to choose between lightdm and gdm when doing that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16877/discussion-between-michael-dykes-and-sbergeron).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got some leftover Xubuntu packages messing with your configs. Try this in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get purge abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview alacarte bison blueman brltty-x11 catfish espeak exo-utils flex fonts-droid fonts-lyx gigolo gmusicbrowser gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs gthumb gthumb-data gtk2-engines-pixbuf indicator-application-gtk2 indicator-sound-gtk2 leafpad libabiword-3.0 libbison-dev libdigest-crc-perl libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libfl-dev libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgstreamer-perl libgtk2-notify-perl libgtk2-trayicon-perl libgtkmathview0c2a libgtkspell0 libido-0.1-0 libindicate-gtk3 libintl-perl libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs libkeybinder0 liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 libnet-dbus-perl liboobs-1-5 libotr5 libots0 librarian0 libsexy2 libtagc0 libthunarx-2-0 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtumbler-1-0 libunique-1.0-0 libvte-common libvte9 libwv-1.2-4 libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-utils libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util6 libxfcegui4-4 libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl lightdm-gtk-greeter link-grammar-dictionaries-en m4 orage parole pastebinit pavucontrol pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog pidgin-otr plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text python-configobj rarian-compat ristretto screensaver-default-images scrollkeeper shimmer-themes system-tools-backends tcl8.5 thunar thunar-archive-plugin thunar-data thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman tumbler tumbler-common xbrlapi xchat xchat-common xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-appfinder xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict xfce4-indicator-plugin xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin xfce4-screenshooter xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-terminal xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-volumed xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4 xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl xubuntu-artwork xubuntu-default-settings xubuntu-desktop xubuntu-docs xubuntu-icon-theme xubuntu-wallpapers && sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

and then reboot.